# Feeds are no longer posted in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, feed

As far as I can tell, at some point today today chat feeds posted in various rooms stopped being posted as chat messages into rooms. What is actually the problem? Can this be fixed?

Some examples where feeds are no longer posted:

- I have created a [room for testing feeds](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1327/2019/4/11). I have included [several feeds](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1327/testing-feeds?tab=feeds) which have relatively large number of posts. Although since I started the room, there have been several new posts in the tags I have chosen. (Among other things, this very post should be caught by the feeds.)
- The [Hot Network Questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/89485/2019/4/11) has feeds to catch all HNQs. (It uses the feeds provided by rene, see: [How to add HNQ to chat room feed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313353#314073) and [How to determine if a question has ever been a “hot network question”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271213#323710)) They stopped being posted at some point today. (This is [the most recent message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49891784#49891784) in that room at the moment.)
- [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595/2019/4/11) has a [feed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8595/the-2nd-monitor?tab=feeds) of all recent questions from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), the feed is called [Captain Obvious](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-786/captain-obvious?tab=recent) and it also stopped making posts in chat today (and there have been several questions since then). The most recent message from that feed as of now [is this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=49891336#49891336).

Comment: I just noticed this too; wonder whether it's related to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326667). Perhaps they're working on chat and unintentionally broke something. Let's hope one of the devs will answer soon.

Comment: It seems that the feed in [Hot Network Questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49895273#49895273) and [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49895207#49895207) - which I mentioned in the question - are now posting messages into the respective chatrooms again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I merged a chat PR earlier that added a couple new checks on room properties when creating a new message. And apparently a room can be null at that point. How? Why? Nobody knows, but null reference exceptions can be quite cruel.

The checks have been corrected and feeds have resumed posting as far as I'm aware. If you're still having an issue with a feed, please comment on this answer with the details and I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It seems that in some rooms I had to remove the feeds and add them again before they started working: [Tagging](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2019/4/12), [Testing feeds](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1327/2019/4/12). However, in the case of testing room they were added after the bug report - so this is probably to be expected. And maybe it would work also in the other room without any intervention if I waited a bit longer.

Comment: I close this answer as a duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) ...