# Chat feed posts into one room, but not another

Tags: support, chat, feed

I've been trying to get a feed up for new HNQ posts on my site, using the implementation from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314073/401104).

The feed URL is https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/interpersonal.stackexchange.com

It's been posting as expected in [a dedicated room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/94066/hnq-feed). However, the feed has [never posted](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-1008/hot-topic-man?tab=recent) to [the main IPS chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/61165/the-awkward-silence), even though we've had 2 posts get to HNQ since it was set up.

Feeds setup for dedicated room (working):

[image]

Feeds setup for main room (not working):

[image]

The only difference I see is that I created a user for the main room feed, but I don't think that should affect it (and it was working with a user in our mod chatroom earlier).

Is this a bug, or something configured incorrectly?

Comment: I've asked this in the Awkward Silence as well but for completeness: Can an RO change the feed for Hot Topic Man and add directly add at the end of the url (no spaces) `-silence`. I need a unique identifier in the feed request to diagnose if the feed is making calls or not.  I'm the owner of that glitch app and I have access to the logging.

Comment: There have been earlier reports of feeds stopping: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326669/feeds-are-no-longer-posted-in-chat?rq=1 but that was across all chat servers and all feeds.

Comment: Testing in that room has completed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rryVc.png. My code works ...

Comment: Even more curious: I changed the feed from a message feed to a ticker feed, and now it seems to work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZChQJ.png ... :/